# Django form DateField initial value not updating

Tags: python, django

In my form I have a field that I want to default as Today when launching the form:

```
class ExpenseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.now(), widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'id':'datepicker'}))
```

Now if I go to the form I see it working correctly, it's got today's date populated, (for example "2018-12-03") but then when I come in tomorrow, it STILL has yesterday's date populated. In fact it will not update until I somehow restart the server.

Any idea? 
Thank you.

Comment: Don't call the method, pass the callable: `initial=datetime.now,`

Comment: thank you. that fixed it. why does calling the method result in such behavior?